# How to update drupal by drush automatically

Tags: drush, updating

In common use,after typing "drush up drupal" it need type "yes" for confirm.If I need to use Linux's cron to run drush automatically,how to bypassing the confirm part?

Comment: Be careful with this. This can cause issues and if there are a lot of things that need updating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating Drupal Core to the latest version e.g. currently Drupal 8

```
drush up drupal -y
```

Updating a specific Drupal Core Version.

```
drush up drupal-7 -y
```

Comment: You may have to add /absolute/path/to/drush @sitealias up drupal -y.

Comment: To expand on @ponies comment. Cron doesn't really load your full environment. So if you have drush on a odd folder and add that into your `.bashrc`, it probably won't be loaded.